# How can I stop Drobox sync during the day and automatically start at night

Tags: sync, dropbox, osx-yosemite, terminal.app, applescript

I'm trying to stop the Dropbox daemon from running during the day.
I'd like to start it and perform a sync around 6 pm daily.
I'm running Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10 on an iMac 27'.

Answer (score 0):

There are no scheduling settings included in this program's default settings, but you can create a cronjob. Google "Mac OS X create cron". Inside the cron job

```
// From the terminal run:
env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

Add the following:

```
// Kill dropbox every morning at 7:00am
* 7 * * * osascript -e 'tell application "Dropbox" to quit'
// Start dropbox every evening at 11:00pm
* 23 * * * open -a "Dropbox"
```

If Dropbox isn't dying properly, use 'killall Dropbox' instead of osascript.

Enjoy